# React: Choosing which project.json file to use based on an if/else statement

Tags: reactjs, project.json

I have a react project that I want to A/B test, but the two test groups require a different setup in my project.json file. Is it possible to set up my project to programmatically pick which project.json setup it uses?

I know the JSON files themselves cannot contain if/else statements, and I don't see any place in my project where you can specify which project.json file to use.

Comment: I doubt you actually mean _" the project definition file used by .NET Core in version 1.0 and earlier"_, so... _package_.json, maybe? _What_ setup?

Comment: Yeah, I have the same questions as @jonrsharpe.  What sort of project is it? What frameworks are you using?  What have you tried?

Comment: I think you have an XY problem here. Can you give more detail about what the different setups are? Or an example that has similar differences but isn't you're exact project? Have you considered using feature flags? These are the most common tool for A/B testing.

Comment: Its a react project